# inserting a NULL to MySql from SQL if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am assigning a variable a numeric value or writing a NULL to it with an if statement, if it's `0.00`.

When writing to MySQL from my PHP page, I'm trying to pass this value and it always writes `0.00` for `NULL`. I'm guessing that's because my insert statement is sending `.$price.` and it sees it as being in quotes?

If I echo `$price` before the insert, it shows me that it's `NULL` but after the insert statement, it never remains.

How can I insert a `NULL`.. since I have to use a variable and send a value if there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert `NULL` into your table, you acutally need to pass the string `"NULL"` into your query, rather than the PHP `NULL` value.  A PHP `NULL`, if enclosed in single-quotes and passed to the query will be interpreted as a `0`.

```
// If $price is NULL in PHP, set it to the string "NULL"
// Otherwise, set it to the current value of $price, but enclosed in single quotes as '$price'
$price = $price === NULL ? "NULL" : "'$price'";

// Then $price gets passed to your query either as NULL or as the single-quoted $price
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl (price) VALUES ($price);");
```

Of course, you have already called `$price = mysql_real_escape_string($price);` before this...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say as you don't post any definitions or code, but probably your table doesn't allow NULL, and so it defaults to the type's "zero" value.